# RestSharp XML DOCTYPE error when request is in JSON

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I've been trying to use RestSharp Library in order to make requests, but when I've tried to make a POST request this error keeps emerging!!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
private readonly string contentType = "application/json";


try
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(new Uri(InvoiceExpressURLS.URL_createClient));

    string clientJsonRequest =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"client\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newClient) + "}")
    );

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    request.AddJsonBody(clientJsonRequest);

    var restResponse = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<object>(request);
    if (restResponse.IsSuccessful)
    {
        response.responseObject = restResponse.Data;
        response.responseMessage = string.Format("The client \"{0}\" was successfuly created.", newClient.name);
    }
    else
    {
        response.responseStatus = restResponse.StatusCode;
        response.responseMessage = restResponse.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    response.responseStatus = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    response.responseMessage = e.Message;
    response.responseObject = e;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error from the service you're posting to? Are you sure your chain of SerializeObject/DeserializeObject/SerializeObject is producing valid Json?

Comment: Open up Fiddler and see what is actually happening on the wire.

Comment: @stuartd yes I'm receiving this from destination! the json is valid

Comment: Do what @Amy said - see what's actually being sent, and what's actually being received.